# oracle sql minus with truncation

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper

I want to compare two tables using the minus command in sqldeveloper (oracle sql).  One table (TABLE A) was generated with a procedure (procedure A) that produced values in column X with the following precision:

80.3921568627

TABLE B (procedure B) produced the following version of the same data:

80.39215686

For the purposes of my task, I do not care about precision beyond two decimal places.  How do I modify the syntax of my query (see below) to ignore all beyond the first two decimal places:

```
select id,a_val
from table_A
minus                               
select id,b_val
from table_B
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `TRUNC`:

```
select id, trunc(a_val, 2) from table_B
minus select id, trunc(b_val, 2) from table_B
```

With `TRUNC` there's no rounding at all, so `TRUNC(12.349, 2) = 12.34`. If you want `12.349` to be treated as equal to `12.35` rather than `12.34`, just use `ROUND` instead of `TRUNC` in the example above.